# Postgres SELECT where value in array

Tags: postgresql

I have a postres table that looks like such: (shortened)

```
id (serial) | col1 (character varying[])
----------------------------------------
1           | {'Life', 'Health', "'VA Data'"}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 'Life' = ANY (col1)
```

The results of this query, is zero records.

The goal being, I want any row, that has the value 'Life' within the col1 array.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Any` should work, but what you are showing me for output for the table is not Life but 'Life'. See the examples below (1. correctly inserted data and what it looks like; 2. incorrectly inserted data and what it looks like-looks like yours; 3. all data):

```
testdb=# select * from test where 'Life' = ANY(col1);
 id |          col1           
----+-------------------------
  1 | {Life,Health,"VA Data"}
(1 row)

testdb=# select * from test where '''Life''' = ANY(col1);
 id |           col1            
----+---------------------------
  2 | {'Life',Health,"VA Data"}
(1 row)

testdb=# select * from test;
 id |           col1            
----+---------------------------
  1 | {Life,Health,"VA Data"}
  2 | {'Life',Health,"VA Data"}
```

Comment: Just to confirm:

It should be:
{Life, Health, VA Data} with no quotes around anything?

Comment: This is what the insertion of the correct data would look like: insert into test(id, col1) values ('1', ARRAY['Life', 'Health', 'VA Data']); See output of query 1 in answer for what it will look like in output.

Comment: @BenjaminBau, say, I have a db with 1.5 million records inserted incorrectly.... but there are only 15 categories... would there be any easy way to correct this mistake with a fancy update command? (or 15 update commands, one per category?)

Comment: I don't know that this can be accomplished with an update statement (unless you know what is in the array for each record). You would have to replace the arrays wholesale. In your position, I would write a stored procedure that iterates through the records, within each record iterates through the array and creates a correctly formatted array that you can update the record to.